# Matrix Multiplication in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like some help on making my solution more functional. At present, I rely heavily on using indexes in my map functions. I am also seeking general feedback and advice, thanks.

```
export const getMatrixColumns = (a: number[][]) => {
  return a[0].length;
};

export const getMatrixRows = (a: number[][]) => {
  return a.length;
};

export const matricesAreValid = (a: number[][], b: number[][]) => {
  return getMatrixColumns(a) === getMatrixRows(b);
};

export const generateEmptyMatrix = (rows: number, cols: number) => {
  return [...Array(rows)].fill(0).map(() => [...Array(cols)].fill(0));
};

export const dotProduct = (a: number[], b: number[]) => {
  return a.map((value, i) => value * b[i]).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
};
export const multiplyMatrices = (a: number[][], b: number[][]) => {
  if (matricesAreValid(a, b)) {
    const rows = getMatrixRows(a);
    const cols = getMatrixColumns(b);
    return generateEmptyMatrix(rows, cols).map((resultRow, i) =>
      resultRow.map((element: number, j: number) => {
        const column = b.map(row => row[j]);
        const row = a[i];
        return dotProduct(row, column);
      })
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

## Concise Function Body

The [function body of an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) can be concise.

For instance can `getMatrixColumns` shorten to

```js
export const getMatrixColumns = (a: number[][]) => a[0].length;
```

---

## Method Name

The method names `getMatrixColumns` and `getMatrixRows` let me expect that the the methods return a `number[]` instead of a `number`.

A better fit are `getMatrixColumnLength` and `getMatrixRowLength`.

---

## Redundant Method Names

Each method name expect `dotProduct` contains some how the word *matrix*.

It is sufficient if the methods are grouped in a `Matrix` module and have names like:

```js
// in matrix.js

export const columnLenghtOf = (a: number[][]) => 
    a[0].length;

export const rowLengthOf = (a: number[][]) => 
    a.length;

export const areValid = (a: number[][], b: number[][]) =>
    columnLenghtOf(a) === columnLenghtOf(b);

/* ... */
```

---

## Type Alias

`Matrix` could be a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) for `number[][]`:

````js
// in matrix.js

type Matrix = number[][]

export const columnLenghtOf = (a: Matrix) => 
    a[0].length;
```
````